# Gauss sums and Dirichlet characters

Tags: characters, gauss-sums

Currently, I'm attending an Analytic Number Theory course, and in the lecture notes I've come across the following statement:

[image]

Does anyone know how to prove this, or at least can give me a reference? Moreover, I'm also confused by the variable $a$, which appears in (5.4) and in (5.5) again. They should be different, right?

Would be very happy with any hint! :)

Best,
python15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dirichlet characters $\bmod q$ are an orthogonal basis of $$\{ v\in \Bbb{C}^q, \gcd(a,q)\ne 1\implies v(a)=0\}$$
With $v(a) = e(a/q)1_{\gcd(a,q)=1}$  then $$\tau(\chi)=\langle v,\overline{\chi}\rangle, \qquad v=\sum_{\chi\bmod q}\overline{\chi}\frac{ \langle v,\overline{\chi}\rangle}{\|\overline{\chi}\|^2}$$

Comment: wow, thank you very much for your answer! after some thinking, it is clear now (: